# Edit changing question to become duplicate?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, editing

Is what I describe below an inappropriate edit?

It can be seen in https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/posts/15029/revisions

A comment points to a site I had already checked and which does NOT answer the question.

The alleged duplicate also does not answer, as it makes it clear that the sites mentioned will not have the SSN for my late wife.

The person editing apparently didn’t notice the “nine years ago” that he/she removed.  And SE apparently thinks people on iPad shouldn’t be allowed to revert edits.

Comment: I suppose that one’s reason for asking is not always relevant, but it certainly sometimes (as this case shows) helps avoid non-answers.

Comment: You can see the SSN at NEHGS's site AmericanAncestors.org.  I've just confirmed that this is still the case, and their database has some results from 2012.

Answer (score 3):

Not inappropriate -- your reason for wanting the information is irrelevant especially as in this case it takes the question to being borderline off-topic (as it isn't about Genealogy and Family History within the scope of this site).

Even without the edit, it's a duplicate: where can I search online for SSN info -- which the question identified as a duplicate answers, including which sites if any provide recent information of the sort you're asking for. It may be that you can't find the info you want online -- but the answer given indicates what you can find and where.

Comment: The other has answers that state why I can not find that information at those sites.  It is neither a duplicate nor does it answer my question.  And your repeat of the inappropriate edit is inconsistent with SE’s request that we “be nice.”.

Comment: @WGroleau being nice is not the same as leaving a bad question unedited. I left the information about the date of death intact and your argument that the other question is not a duplicate -- the other information is superfluous here as well as off-topic.

Comment: @WGroleau I wouldn't have edited out the fact that your spouse died nine years ago, but the existing question explains why you can't find the information at sites like Ancestry, RootsWeb, or Genealogy Bank, and shows how the access to the SSN has gotten more restricted over the past several years.  Your question didn't say where you had already looked aside from FamilySearch, so there's no way for us to tell that you had already reviewed what was on the site.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from its timeline the only edit made to your question, prior to it being made a duplicate by another user, was by me, and that just added a tag.  Consequently, the decision to make it a duplicate appears to have been made based on the original content of your question body.

[image]

I am very sorry for the loss of your wife nine years ago but I hope you will appreciate that we need to be very cautious on this site when dealing with questions that involve anyone born less than 100 years ago.

My later edit to remove the statement of urgency was to ensure that your question was treated on its technical merits within the scope of this site.  We can take no responsibility for you having discarded your tax returns and not being able to find a death certificate.

I am not a US citizen but my understanding is that, as your late wife's spouse, you could contact the United States Social Security Administration (SSA) to obtain this information.  It is they who are best placed to verify your identity, and entitlement to the information.

I believe our site has done its best to provide you with an answer within the guidelines and policies under which it operates.

Comment: The action to mark as a duplicate was mine, and I can confirm that I made it based on the original content.